# asp.net mvc optional parameter

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, url-routing

I am trying here to kinda merge 2 routes in 1 with asp.net mvc

These routes are :

> http://www.example.com/e/1

and

> http://www.example.com/e/1,name-of-the-stuff

Currently it is set as this in the Global.asax.cs :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "EventWithName",
    "e/{id},{name}",
    new { controller = "Event", action = "SingleEvent", id = "" },
    new { id = @"([\d]+)" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SingleEvent",
    "e/{id}",
    new { controller = "Event", action = "SingleEvent", id = "" },
    new { id = @"([\d]+)" }
);
```

I tried to handle it by modifying the 1st route like this one :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "EventWithName",
    "e/{id}{name}",
    new { controller = "Event", action = "SingleEvent", id = "" },
    new { id = @"([\d]+)", name = @"^,(.*)" }
);
```

It is not working as I need to separate the 2 parameters with a slash or at least a character.

My most possible idea to solve this would be using the regex, as I only need the id part. The name is only descriptive and used for SEO purposes. Basically is there a way to use some kind of Regex of the type of `([\d]+),(.*)` and the for `id = "$1"` or something like that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it helps

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{*keywords}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 0 },
    new { id = "(\\d+)" }
);
```

Comment: I would need to format my URLs like this : http://www.example.com/Events/SingleEvent/1/name-of-the-stuff, which is not exactly what I look for.

Comment: Not necessarily. The key point of this answer is the {*keywords} part. Try adding the '*' to your route, with the comma.  If the ",foo" part is optional, try using two routes, first with both parts, second with just the {id}.

Comment: Brannon is right. I think the format `/1/what-is-new` is better than `/1,what-is-new`. As you can see in the StackOverflow qustion url. anyway, you can not use two parameters in the same segment or a literal text between them.

Comment: It seems it is the easiest way to work around. I'll use it for now and see later I guess :-) thanks for the pointer!